# How to install ddrescue on Chrome OS via crosh or terminal?

Tags: software-installation, chrome-os, ddrescue

I see that `dd` is installed in `Chrome OS`. I can access it both from `crosh` and the `terminal`. ddrescue is not installed. There is no `apt-get` command. How do I install `ddrescue` with either crosh or terminal on Chrome OS?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Chrome OS (I think v69+) has support for Linux apps. Just had to turn on the Linux (beta) support for apps and then I was able to install ddrescue (GNU) from the Linux terminal.

Separate question would be for ddrescue-gui, as I think Chrome OS switched to Gentoo Linux some time ago and I don't think there is a binary of ddrescue-gui for Gentoo -- just source code which must be compiled to binary. I could be wrong. Maybe there is a version out there which is compatible with Chrome OS.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratulations on figuring out the answer yourself. In order to make it more helpful for others facing a similar problem, please consider adding more step-by-step instructions to explain how you solved it, or which resources you found helpful in solving the problem.